# your device isn't compatible with this version - android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I am unable to download an app on android 5.0 even if I have set following code in manifest  :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="package"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0">

<!-- for card.io card scanning -->
<compatible-screens>
    <!-- <screen android:screenSize="normal" />
       <screen android:screenSize="large" />-->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="normal" />
    <!-- all large size screens -->
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="ldpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="mdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="hdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
    <screen
        android:screenDensity="xhdpi"
        android:screenSize="large" />
</compatible-screens>

<supports-screens
    android:anyDensity="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:smallScreens="false"
    android:xlargeScreens="false" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="false" />
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus"
    android:required="false" />

<permission
    android:name="package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.AUTHENTICATE_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="package.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.KILL_BACKGROUND_PROCESSES" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true" />
```

I have set minSdk version as 16 and targetsdkversion as 22.

Gradle :

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '23.0.0 rc2'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "app.qourier"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 9
    versionName "1.2.7"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: `I have set minSdk version = 16 and targetsdkversion as 22.`. Why dont we see that in your manifest file? That would be the first things in it i would think.

Comment: Go to your File ->Project structure -> Properties tab -> Change compile sdk version & build sdk version to your requirement.

Comment: @greenapps I think he is talking about the one in the gradle file !

Comment: Can we see your `Build.Gradle` code.

Comment: @jaydroider updated with gradle code

Comment: try to remove that compatible screen in your manifest

Comment: Thanks @RashidCordero

Comment: there is a good chance that your device is xxhdpi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Compatible screens from manifest